# sqlexception message display causes error on page

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, sqlexception

I have a aspx page with several input fields(couple of int's and strings) and 3rd party gridview. 
Data is validated, and stored procedure is called from code behind to save data in DB.

Gridview has capability to display error box to user which can be called from code behind. So when I catch exception I give it my error message(error message is
something like:"Data can't be saved to database. Error:" & ex.message and call function that displays errorbox.

Normally this works great, but (Oh, do I hate this but's) when trying to display sqlexception, I get javascript/html error on page and no error box is displayed.

I have come to conclusion that ex.message contains some characters that canot be displayed by this javascript/html errorbox.

So, I tried to use System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ex.message), but it didn't work.

Just out of curiosity I also did System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ex.message) and then I was able to display the error message, but of course it had "+" instead of white spaces

Example: Cannot+insert+duplicate+key+row+in+object+'dbo.TableName'+with+unique+index+'IX_Unique_Dan'.%0d%0aThe+statement+has+been+terminated.

Is there a built-in way to remove unwanted characters, eofs and similar? 
At the moment I'm using my function named CleanString which checks chars in string. 
It looks like this...

```
For Each c As Char In value.ToCharArray()
    If (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)) Then
        msg = msg & c
    ElseIf (c = ".") Then
        msg = msg & "."

        .
        .
        .

    Else
        msg = msg & " "
    End If
Next
```

Tnx,
Benxy

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to escape quotes? replace every single quote with a backslashed single quote.

can you paste the exact browser error message with the javascript/html source lines where the error is happening.

Comment: I've checked escape quotes. Problem seems to be as I stated above with Line Feed and Carrige Return.
Here is the output from Debug Toolbar:


Line: 27
Character: 1497
Code: 0
Error Message: Unterminated string constant

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely to be a problem with the error message and HtmlEncode(), and more likely some other javascript running on your page that's causing the issue.

Provide the error message here and we can tell for sure.

Also, is this public-facing? You really shouldn't be displaying internal errors to the user, especially not when it comes from the database, you could be opening up a security hole.

Comment: Problem is not in error message it self, problem is with this 3rd party grid view and %0d%0a within ex.message. Error box of gridview can't parse line feed and carrige return. So basiclly I was wondering is there a built in solution to clean such stuff.

At the moment best solution that I have come up with is this:


For Each err As SqlError In ex.Errors
    errMessage = errMessage & err.Message
Next


This way I get every error message, but without LF & CR

Comment: Yes, I am aware of showing error message to user, but at the moment this is desirable. No matter how strange it sounds.. :)

Comment: Noooo, internal messages should never be presented to the user! :) Write them out to a log file or something. Elmah, Log4Net are good for this. Just supply a "An error has occured, please contact support" message when an exception is caught...

You could spend a lot of time trying to fix a problem here that you really don't need to.

But to answer your question, a regular expression to strip all but alpha-numeric characters and some punctuation would work.

Comment: Showing internal messages to user is not an issue here as I stated before. 
I am aware what user should see and what shouldn't see.
Regex you say, could try that... Thanks for your help..